# What form of home address did Romans use?

Tags: roman-empire, roman-republic, ancient-rome

Were the buildings in an ancient Roman city numbered, named or something else? How would they tell each other where they lived? Were the numbers painted on the walls? Did they have apartment numbers? What would've happened when they wanted to know where to go? Where would they tell their servants to take them?

Comment: As others have said in the answers they might have used addresses. For the record many places in the world today (e.g. Africa) don't use house numbers/addresses for post.

Comment: ILXVIII Via Appia ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I visited Rome and also Pompeii last week.  According to our tour guide and the evidence left by the protection provided to the ruins of Pompeii by the eruption of Mount Vesuvius, citizens of Pompeii in 79 AD did have street names and house numbers.  Some even had signs in the entry way to their home warning “Cave Canem” or “Beware of Dog”.

Comment: Pompeii are well covered by the google street view. It would be nice to have a link to the street address evidence and to the cave canem sign.

Comment: @horsh, may be these ones? http://storage7.static.itmages.ru/i/13/0522/h_1369244311_8406019_6d7d943b60.png
http://storage5.static.itmages.ru/i/13/0522/h_1369244343_8732927_8b1e518302.png

Comment: Those ones look suspiciously modern.

Comment: I would appreciate authoritative info on this

Comment: @horsh Indeed, this site http://www.pompeiiinpictures.com/pompeiiinpictures/R0/name_index.htm says "The original Roman house names and numbers are not known."

Comment: @horsh Can't find any sources on the net but I heard the same thing about the "Beware of Dog" signs from my Latin teacher about 12 years ago